# Serialize Django Queryset to JSON for Celery before execution

Tags: django, celery, django-queryset

I am given a Queryset from an external library and - since Querysets are lazy - I'd like to serialize it to JSON *before* it is accessed, and thus executed, in the DB, so it may be executed in an asynchronous Celery task instead.

My question is, is there a way of representing the essential elements of a Queryset as JSON so I don't have to use Pickle?

I know I could get the raw query with `queryset.query`, but since I'd have to execute a raw query at the other end, I don't much like that idea.

### Details

The specific use-case here is evaluating the Queryset in a task so the results can then be exported to a file and dumped on a server for later access.

The result set can be quite large, so doing the export as part of a standard request/response cycle can often timeout.

The request is generated from a Django Admin change view list filter. I've tried going back through the list filter code, but it seems like it just generates filter objects - not suitable for JSON serialization.

I could look at the list filter query string and re-evaluate all of the keys into a Queryset filter, but many of the filters are `SimpleListFilter` classes that also just return filter objects, and don't reveal real Queryset filters in the URL. I'd need to recreate logic for these filters just to get a kwarg-style filter that can be JSON serialized.

Comment: Please post some code you wrote to accomplish this. What exactly are you trying to do inside a celery task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update for Django 1.11 & Celery 3.0

This, sadly, no longer works. If anyone has any information on how to properly serialize a queryset, or its various filters and properties, before execution, please let me know.

### Original answer

It turns out that `my_queryset.query` is the correct and safe way to serialize a QuerySet before execution.

> If you only want to pickle the necessary information to recreate the QuerySet from the database at a later time, **pickle the query attribute of the QuerySet**. You can then recreate the original QuerySet (without any results loaded) using some code like this:

```
import pickle
query = pickle.loads(s)     # Assuming 's' is the pickled string.
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
qs.query = query            # Restore the original 'query'.
```

> The query attribute is an opaque object. It represents the internals of the query construction and is not part of the public API. However, **it is safe (and fully supported) to pickle and unpickle the attribute’s contents as described here**.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets

This talks about using pickle, but it does, of course, work with the JSON serializer, too.

```
# admin.py
...
    export_data.delay(queryset.query)
...

# tasks.py
@task(serializer='json')
def export_data(query):
    qs = MyModel.objects.all()
    qs.query = query
...
```

Answer (score 2):

At time of writing, using Python 3.7+ and Django 2.2 the `pickle` dumps/loads seems to work.
It is missing just a `queryset.update()` in the end.

I tried something like:

```
# packing
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
serialized_queryset = pickle.dumps(queryset.query)

# unpacking
restored = MyModel.objects.all()
restored.query = pickle.loads(serialized_queryset)
restored.update()
```

and it works fine. Not tested across celery tasks yet, but I expect it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you know if this works with the JSON serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to serialize the `QuerySet` to access it in the Celery task. You can use your Django models and create `QuerySet` in the task itself. If there's some specific way the `QuerySet` is created, you can put `QuerySet` creation code in a common function or class and import this shared code both in the web application code and in the Celery task.

There's no reason to avoid using Django ORM in Celery tasks.

Comment: Thanks, but the Queryset comes from an external library, and rather than deconstruct how the Queryset came to be, I was hoping I could just use the returned Queryset, and separate out its filters, etc.

I fully intend to execute a query using the Django ORM once I run the task, I just don't want to have to pickle a Queryset.

Comment: But why can't you use the external library in the Celery task? What is the point of constructing it in the web view and then jumping through the hoops to pass it to the celery task when you can use this external library in Celery task directly.

Comment: It's generated from a selection in the Django admin, but the filters aren't simple. I've been through it, and it looks like Django admin generates filter objects directly - they're never turned into a dict that could be supplied to a `filter()` after being serialized and passed to Celery. If there's an easier way to capture the filters from a list view and convert them to filters on the Celery side, that would certainly help. Perhaps capturing the entire URL and passing it through the relevant class methods at the other end is the way to go.

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide more details about your project and what you're doing with these admin filters, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `decode` and `encode` query. With **Django 2.1** and **Celery 4.2** works with this code:

```py
query_dump = pickle.dumps(queryset.query).decode('latin1')

query = pickle.loads(query_dump.encode('latin1'))
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. Does this avoid the security issues with using `pickle`?